# Why is my counter adding more than one each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a test using jQuery, but can't work out why when the correct answer is used my counter variable, `count`, seems to go up by more than one.

```
function nextQuestion(){
    $('#submit').show();
    $('#next').hide();
    $('#result').text('');
    $('#value').val('');
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length));
    $('#englishWord').text(words[randomNumber][0]);
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if ($('#value').val() == words[randomNumber][1])
        {
            $('#result').text("You are correct, well done");
            $('#submit').hide();
            $('#next').show();

            $('#next').click(function(){
                count = count + 1;
                $('#score').text(count); 
                nextQuestion();              
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            $('#result').text("That is incorrect, try again");
            count = 0;
            $('#score').text(count);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is your counter, count ? tha Math.random() generates number between 0 and 1 , I don't get how you use that as random number

Comment: Yeah the counter variable is count

Comment: You should prive a working example of your problem...this is just a part of code

Comment: and the random generator makes a number between 1 and the length of the 'words' array

Comment: between 0 and number of words :) but now I got it ; ) you should include more code

Comment: all the relevent code for the count is included but i have provided you an working example anyway

https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=e9OzRD9Vc5

Comment: When `nextQuestion` is called, a listener is added on the `#submit` element, which calls `nextQuestion`, which adds another listener, which calls `nextQuestion`, which adds another listener...

Comment: I see, how can nextQuestion be called without adding lots of listeners?

Comment: Have you tried binding the event to mouseup?

Comment: A simple solution.. just call $('#next').off('click'); at the start of the function.

Comment: Debugging hint: Next time you have this kind of a situation, put an alert in front of the line that seems to not be working right ` count = count + 1;`, in this case, you would have seen it executed once on the first click, twice on the second click and more.  That might have been enough to lead you to the answer on your own.

Answer (score 3):

`count` is increasing by more than one each time there is a click on `#next` because you are adding multiple anonymous listeners to the `click` event of the `#next` element. Each of those functions is independently adding `1` to `count`. Thus, when `#next` is clicked, `count` goes up 1 for each anonymous listener you have added to the `click` event on the `#next` element.

Every time there is a click on `#submit` and `$('#value').val() == words[randomNumber][1]` you execute:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    count = count + 1;
    $('#score').text(count); 
    nextQuestion();              
});
```

This results in a new anonymous function being added as a listener to the `#next` element's `click` event in addition to any ones already listening for that event. Thus, each time there is a `click` event on `#next` tehre are multiple functions called which each increases the `count` by 1. The total amount of the increase for each click on `#next` depends on how many functions you have listening to that event.

You have the same problem with the `click` event for the `#submit` element. This causes `count` to increase even further by adding even more listeners to the `click` event of the `#next` element. The first time `#submit` is clicked one listener is added. On the the second `#submit` click two listeners to the `#submit` `click` event each add another listener to the `#next` `click` event making a total of 3 listeners on that event. Thus, `count` goes up by 3. This continues to scale as you add more and more listeners to each event.

#### Have your code add the event listeners only once

The solution to this is to only assign those click events once:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if ($('#value').val() == words[randomNumber][1])
    {
        $('#result').text("You are correct, well done");
        $('#submit').hide();
        $('#next').show();
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#result').text("That is incorrect, try again");
        count = 0;
        $('#score').text(count);
    }
});

$('#next').click(function(){
    count = count + 1;
    $('#score').text(count); 
    nextQuestion();              
});

function nextQuestion(){
     $('#submit').show();
     $('#next').hide();
     $('#result').text('');
     $('#value').val('');
     randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length));
     $('#englishWord').text(words[randomNumber][0]);
}
```

#### Alternately, use a named function and rely on [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to ignore your attempts to add identical listeners.

An alternate solution is to use a single named function, which is defined in a scope such that it is not redefined each time the code adding it is called. Listeners which are not added using [event attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes) (e.g. `<div onclick="doSomething();">`) are added using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (jQuery uses this method inside the various methods it provides for adding event listeners).  If you try to add the same function, using the same values for the other parameters to `addEventListener()`, then the [additional listeners are discarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners). That means that even if you try to add the same function, with the same parameters, more than once, it will only be called once per event. With an anonymous function, the function is separately defined each time that code is run. Thus, while the code is the same, the function that is defined is separate from any prior time the code has run. As a result, multiple copies get added.

However, just because the function has a name does not mean that it is defined in a scope that will result in it not being redefined each time it is added.  For instance, in the above code, if the function for the `#next` listener was defined within the `#submit` listener, and even if it had a name, it would still be redefined every time the `#submit` listener was run. To prevent the function from being redefined, the key is how and where the function is defined, not just that it is a named function. However, in order to refer to that function it must have a name, or otherwise be associated with a variable. Thus, you will generally find that there is an assumption made when someone says a "named function" that it is defined in a way that it is not, normally, redefined.

Comment: This is mostly right. But a named function wouldn't help - at least, not if the function is defined inside the `'#submit'` handler. You'd get the same problem. If you used a named function defined in the outer scope then both `$('#next').click` calls would use the same handler, rather than different handlers that just happen to do the same thing. But I doubt this would help - I don't believe it checks for equality of functions. If it does work then the important point is not whether the function is named, but where it is declared. In js it never matters whether functions are named.

Comment: @DavidKnipe, You are correct. I wrote that with the unstated assumption that the named function would be defined in way, and scope, such that it was not redefined each time either of the event handlers were called. I have rewritten that. However, [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) does specifically [prevent the same function from being added more than once on the same target, with the same parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners).