# How can prevent my code from running an increasing number of times each time I click a button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**how can I close instance of chrome extension by clicking browserAction button..?**

I am working on chrome extension, in which I want to activate the extension by clicking on browserAction button and when I click it again I want to close the actual instance of that extension so that I can start it again fresh by clicking browserAction icon again.

https://gist.github.com/p10shinde/fb24e5c01d435d138a9bcfdb5b1734aa

**add jquery.js**

**background.js**

```
var actvTabId;
var toggle = false;


chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{

ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:1234/");

toggle = !toggle;

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
    { 
                actvTabId = tab.id

            if(toggle)
            {   
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ tabId : actvTabId,color: "green" });
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId : actvTabId,text: 'R'});

                    chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs)
                    {
                        for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tabs[i].selected == true)
                            {
                                //sending to active tab (myscript) from back 
                                try
                                {
                                //send to active tab to myscript from backgrund
                                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {from : 'btn_record2',msg : 'dontremove'}, function(response) {});
                                alert('sent');
                                }
                                catch(e){}
                            }
                        }
                    });


                chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
                {
                    if ( request.from =='btn_record_myscript' )
                    {
                        if(typeof(request) != 'undefined')
                        {
                            var msg = {cmd : request.command,trgt : request.target , val : request.value};
                            //sending to java desktop app (can comment)
                            //ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
                            alert('sent to java');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
            ws.close();
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({tabId : actvTabId, color: "red" });
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId : actvTabId,text: ''});
            }






        ws.onopen = function opn() {

           console.log('Connection Successfull.');

        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {

            console.log("From Server : "+evt.data);
        };

        ws.onclose = function() {
           // alert("Closed!");
           console.log('closed');
           ws.close();
        };

        ws.onerror = function(err) {
            //alert("Error: " + err);
            console.log('Connection Failed. Check if server is up and running.');
        };

    }); 

});
```

**myScript.js**

```
var typed = '';
var events = [];

        chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message,sender, sendResponse)
        {
            if(message.from === 'btn_record2')
            {
                alert('gotchaa');
                if(message.msg == 'remove')
                {
                    alert("1");
                    monitorEvents({'main' : document, 'actn':'rem'});
                    alert('removed');
                }
                else if(message.msg == 'dontremove')
                {
                    alert("2");
                    monitorEvents({'main' : document, 'actn':'add'});
                    alert('added');
                }

            }

                function monitorEvents(element) 
                {
                    //handler
                    var log = function(e) 
                    { 
                         if(typeof(e.toElement) != 'undefined' )
                        {
                            if(e.type == 'click' || e.type == 'change')
                            {
                              console.log(e);
                              var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(e.target.nodeName);
                              var target_lcl = createXPathFromElement(ele[0]);

                              chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'btn_record_myscript',command : e.type,target:target_lcl,value:''});

                                      if(typeof(e.toElement.href) != 'undefined')
                                       monitorEvents(document);
                              }
                        }
                      else
                      {
                        if(e.type == 'change')
                        console.log(e);

                        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(e.target.nodeName);
                        var target_lcl = createXPathFromElement(ele[0]);
                        typed = e.target.value;
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'btn_record_myscript', command : 'type' , target : target_lcl , value : typed});
                      }

                    }


                      for(var i in element.main) 
                      {
                        if(i.startsWith("on")) 
                            events.push(i.substr(2));
                      }

                      events.forEach(function(eventName) 
                      {
                            if(element.actn == 'add')
                            {
                                element.main.addEventListener(eventName, log,false);
                            }
                            else if(element.actn == 'rem')
                            {
                                element.main.removeEventListener(eventName, log,false);
                            }
                      }); 
                }
        });


        ////new xpath element (is being used)
        //dont bother about this function
        function createXPathFromElement(elm) 
        { 
            var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
            for (var segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) 
            { 
                if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
                        var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
                        for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                            if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                            if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
                        }; 
                        if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                            segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                            return segs.join('/'); 
                        } else { 
                            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
                        } 
                } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
                    segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
                } else { 
                    for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                        if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++; }; 
                        segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
                }; 
            }; 
            return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
        };
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "WindowFetchDOMExtension",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" : "This extension fetches the DOM of current page.",
"icons": { "48": "bear.png"},

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": { "16": "bear.png", "32": "bear.png" },
    "default_title": "WindowFetch DOM"
},
"permissions": ["tabs"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js","myScript.js"]
}]
}
```

Added information describing the problem from OP comment:
It's a single extension. When I turn it on, it captures click events. When I click the browserAction icon again, it should stop listening to click events. Now here is problem: when I click start it again, it listens two times for that event. If I turn it off and on again then it would listen 4 times for a single click event.

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? What does the extension do when "activated"? Are you trying to control an extension using another extension?

Comment: no. Its single extension. When I turn it on, it captures click events. And when I click browserAction icon again it should stop listening to click events.

Now here is problem, when I click start it again it listens two times for that event and if I turn it off and on again then it would listen 4 times for a single click event. Hope problem is clear...

Comment: The problem is clearly "I have a bug in my code", not "how to do something vague". You should include relevant code and then we can help.

Comment: I'm uploading the code..

Comment: Note: "include" means "edit the question to add properly formatted code, and not a link somewhere". "Relevant" means "do not dump all of your code, only parts that you think matter for this".

Comment: https://gist.github.com/p10shinde/fb24e5c01d435d138a9bcfdb5b1734aa

Comment: Please create a **minimal** [mcve], not dump all of your poorly formatted code (many auto-formatters, which will at least auto-indent, are available) into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code is executing multiple times per event: Multiple downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368063/code-is-executing-multiple-times-per-event-multiple-downloads)

Comment: Regarding it being a duplicate: Specifically, see your code line: `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(...`.

Comment: A duplicate with more explanation: [Why is my counter adding more than one each time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808272/why-is-my-counter-adding-more-than-one-each-time). Anyone know of a canonical duplicate target for this type of problem? Obviously, I'm familiar with the ones where I wrote answers, but this type of problem is common enough such that there should be other, more canonical, dup targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted below,

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message,sender, sendResponse)
    {
        if(message.from === 'btn_record2')
        {...}
    });
```

I have used **chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(dostuff);** and inside

```
function dostuff(message,sender, sendResponse)
        {
        chrome.extension.onMessage.removeListener(dostuff);
         //rest code below
        }
```

to remove previous listener and it solved my problem.

**Avoid using anonymous functions.**