# Chrome WebRequest - Add chrome event listener once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Problem**

- I'm trying to pass headers to a chrome extension that is running in a
  tab. At the moment my current code, adds one event each time the page is refreshed which means if you refresh on the same page 5 times, by the end the event is triggered 5 times on each page load.

**Restrictions**

- I have to run the tab using a background script to allow the user to
  exclude sites it runs on.
- In order to get the specific headers I want, I have to listen using a background extension because, attempts to re-request the resource are CORS and have access to a reduced set of headers.

**Code**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Prevent double firing of event - extension should run once on complete.
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {          
         chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
             function(details) {
                 console.log(details);
                 // Pseudo code, where things are pulled from storage
                 // Based on this I then:
                 executeScript(tabId, "built_seo_traffic.js");
             },
             {
                urls: ["*://*/*"],
                types: ["main_frame"],
                tabId: tab.id
            },
            ["responseHeaders"]
         );
    }
});
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried setting a variable which checks if the event has already fired, however I can only get this so the script then runs once across all the tabs, rather than once on each tab.

Am I tackling this correctly? I am just missing something which makes this easy?

Comment: You need to remove the listener when it fires: add a name to the function and pass it to chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.removeListener inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I was struggling a little bit with how to get all the information passed in, but worked it out thanks to your pointer in the right direction. Feel free to post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my counter adding more than one each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808272/why-is-my-counter-adding-more-than-one-each-time)

Comment: Similar problem, but the solution here is different, because the named function also has to reference removing a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm I managed to get the following solution:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Prevent double firing of event - extension should run once on complete.
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {          
         chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
             executeTrafficLights,
             {
                urls: ["*://*/*"],
                types: ["main_frame"],
                tabId: tab.id
            },
            ["responseHeaders"]
         );
    }
});


executeTrafficLights(details){
    console.log(details);
    // Pseudo code, where things are pulled from storage
    // Based on this I then:
    executeScript(tabId, "built_seo_traffic.js");

    // Then remove self after executing
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.removeListener(executeTrafficLights);
}
```

Notably the part I had been struggling with was that because the named function can only be called without parameters I wasn't sure how to pass in tabId and tab.

Turns out both the pieces of information I needed from those (the tabId and the URL) are in the details object.

Unsure if there is any other information contained in `tab` which isn't in `details`, but for me this worked great!

Comment: @Makyen Ah I was trying to make it more general. Let me change that back.